# problema con guardar file en laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel-7

Hola hace tiempo no me daba errores esta cosa lo que pasa es que intento almacenar un archivo en laravel7 mediante un imput type file pero al momento de guardar la ruta me guarda el nombre del archivo mas public/'nombre del ARCHIVO  Y SOLO QUIERO QUE ME GUARDE el nombre

paso codigo

este es mi controlador para guardar el request

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$seguimiento_up=Request()->except('_token');

        

        $fecha = $request->input('fecha');
        $descripcion = $request->input('descripcion');
        $evidencia = $request->file('evidencia')->store('public')->getClientOriginalName();
        $registro_id = $request->input('registro_id');

        $seguimiento_up = array(
            'fecha' => $fecha,
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'evidencia' =>$evidencia,
            'registro_id' => $registro_id,
        );

        seguimientos::create($seguimiento_up);
        return redirect('seguimientos')->with('success', 'Seguimiento guardado correctamente. ');

        //return response()->json($seguimiento_up);
        //echo asset('storage/$evidencia');
    }
```

public/a9KXOz2S2CAUwxhOixHX50Y1jSUbiLjzYV2ju8O5.docx //esto es lo que me guarda en la DB y quiero quitarle el public/

gracias de antemano

Comment: yo se que es dontro del request pero no se como

Comment: prueba lo siguiente:  $evidencia = $request->file('evidencia')->getClientOriginalName();